# What is meant by Though of?

Tags: meaning

> Get me a giant cauldron?” said Aeger, looking brighter. “Then we can brew all we need”. There was a great guffaw in the hall. “Invited us to stay for a while, have you Aeger?”
> “Of Course I’ll help, I said, but where will I find a cauldron big enough for all of us?” My friend Tyr, a brave young god, **though of giant stock**, and full of courage piped up: “We can take my father’s, it must be a mile deep!”

What is meant by ‘though of giant stock’?

Comment: "Stock" can mean "ancestry", and that is how it is being used here.

Answer (score 2):

In this context the "though" is "although".

The sentence suggests that brave young gods are not usually from the race or lineage of giants. Tyr was an exception.

Comment: "Though **he was** of giant stock" is implied.